# How can I create an object from aaa array in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```js
const aaa = [
  {
    "objectid": 111,
    "userid": "1",
    "associationid": "123"
  },
  {
    "objectid": 111,
    "userid": "2",
    "associationid": "456"
  }
];

//Need to create an object like the following:
//{"objectid": "111", "contacts" : [{"isdelete": "1", "contactid": "1", "associationid":"123"},{"isdelete": "1", "contactid": "2", "associationid":"456"}]}

//I tried the following but it doesn't work:
 aaa.reduce((accumulator, {objectid,userid,associationid}) =>
  ({ ...accumulator, "objectid": objectid, "contacts": (accumulator["contacts"] || []).push(({"isdelete": "1", "contactid": userid, associationid})) }),
  {})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with an object to store the values for each id.

```js
const arr = [
  {
    "objectid": 111,
    "userid": "1",
    "associationid": "123"
  },
  {
    "objectid": 111,
    "userid": "2",
    "associationid": "456"
  }
];
let res = Object.values(
  arr.reduce((acc, {objectid, userid, associationid}) => {
    (acc[objectid] ??= {objectid, contacts : []}).contacts
      .push({isdelete: '1', contactid: userid, associationid});
    return acc;
  }, {})
);
console.log(res);
// use res[0] to get just the first object itself
```

Comment: Txs all a lot. Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[`#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) returns the array length and not the new array. You can use [`#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) instead while wrapping the pushed item into another array, if you are looking for a short code.

Fromt the docs:

> The push() method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and returns the new length of the array.

> The concat() method is used to merge two or more arrays. This method does not change the existing arrays, but instead returns a new array.

```js
const aaa = [
  {
    "objectid": 111,
    "userid": "1",
    "associationid": "123"
  },
  {
    "objectid": 111,
    "userid": "2",
    "associationid": "456"
  }
];

//Need to create an object like the following:
//{"objectid": "111", "contacts" : [{"isdelete": "1", "contactid": "1", "associationid":"123"},{"isdelete": "1", "contactid": "2", "associationid":"456"}]}

//I tried the following but it doesn't work:
const ans = aaa.reduce((accumulator, {objectid,userid,associationid}) =>
  ({ ...accumulator, "objectid": objectid, "contacts": (accumulator["contacts"] || []).concat([{"isdelete": "1", "contactid": userid, associationid}]) }),
  {})
  
  console.log({ans});
```

Comment: Ideally you should not ALWAYS look for short code, while you are unsure of what it does. Simpler, easier to read code is better.

Comment: Txs all a lot. Appreciated.